# http request user agent encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, httprequest, xss

we are using izenda as our report manager (third-party) everything is good.
we are using asp.net MVC C#.
but we have security issue on their settings page  Status & Utils

they are showing user agent in their setting pages without encoding

I changed my user agent request by live HTTP header tools from

```
Mozilla/5.0 (MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
```

to

```
Mozilla/5.0<script>alert('test xss')</script> (MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
```

and I saw when I'm going to setting the JavaScript shows me that alert

because it rendered this elements to me

```
<br>Ad Hoc version: 6.8.0.3
<br>.NET version: v2.0.50727
<br>ResponseServer: rs.aspx
<br>AdHocConfig: CustomAdHocConfig (DatabaseAdHocConfig).
<br>Windows version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
<br>Server version: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
<br>Browser data: Mozilla/5.0<script>alert('test xss')</script> (MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
<br>Maximum processors count: 8
<br>Current processors count: 4
...
```

I add my security report [image]

I can't change before rendering html elements because it made by izenda's dll , I just like to know is there a way to encoding user agent for entire system?

Comment: This is not even worth worrying about, if all you can do through this is run JavaScript then who cares, its not like you're running any code of the server, you'll only effect yourself!!

Comment: I add our security reports

Comment: You could try using a handler or module to strip it out or what ever you desire. Every request will pass through this

Comment: HttpRequestBase.UserAgent doesn't have setter / I can't change it in filter